# Problem with finding data within region using BingMaps api?

Tags: javascript, maps, bing-maps, bing, bing-api

We are facing some issue with bing maps. We are ploting data on HTML file by region and when we search by region as United Kingdom or China it takes too much time to return value.
We are using below method to get data from bing maps and check whether pushpin is within added region or not.

```
if (Microsoft.Maps.SpatialMath.Geometry.contains(searchAreaDraw, pins[i]))
{
    // Checking Code
}
```

Here searchAreaDraw is premitive or geometry of plotted shape. In this case United Kingdom or China region. We are getting approx 12,000+ bounds for UK region and the method takes to much time to execute. We also tried with intersection of BingMaps SpatialMath service but it also takes too much time to execute.

If anyone have idea then please share.

**Technology**: HTML, CSS, Javascript, Jquery and Bing Maps API

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with larger datasets, spatial calculations should be done within a database. Spatial calculations are generally fairly compute intensive. The spatial math library in the Bing Maps SDK is meant for on the fly client side calculations and should only be used with smaller data sets (the browser can only do so much). Even in a database where spatial indexes are used, calculations on larger datasets can take time. If you are using Azure, an easy option is to use SQL. It has built in spatial support: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15